# How to use Mac command key in Jupyter lab

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

In Settings > Advansced Settings Editor > Keyboard Shortcuts, I am trying to re-map some of the keys to use with Command key in Macbook. I tried "Cmd" and "Command", both of which didn't work. Is there a key defined for Command key in Jupyter lab?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same problem. The key "Command" is called "Accel" in Jupyterlab.

Comment: Which version of Jupyter Lab are you using? I tried changing to "Accel" in the Settings, but it doesn't seem to work